# React- Lodash without() method rendering empty after state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am new to React and I have run into some difficulty I cannot seem to figure out.

I am using Lodash to remove a single object from an array, via an onClick eventHandler. However once I select to delete a specific item, the display is rendered as empty, However When I console.log the returned Array it shows the elements are present but wrapped in a lodashWrapper.

Also the element I selected for removal is still in the Array.

I am using the lodash method without and I have included all relevant snippets.

```
class App extends Component
{  
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state =
    {
      appointments : [],
      idx : 0,       
    }
    this.deleteAppointment = this.deleteAppointment.bind(this)
  }

  deleteAppointment(apt)
  {    
    let temp = this.state.appointments;
    console.log(temp);
    temp = without(temp,apt)
    console.log(temp);
    this.setState({
      appointments : temp
    });    
  }
<ListAppointment appointments = {this.state.appointments}
                deleteAppointment={this.deleteAppointment} />

class ListAppointment extends Component
{    

    render()
    {        
        return (            
        <div className="appointment-list item-list mb-3">
          {this.props.appointments.map(item =>(
                <div className="pet-item col media py-3" key={item.aptID}>
            <div className="mr-3">
              <button className="pet-delete btn btn-sm btn-danger"
               onClick={()=> this.props.deleteAppointment(item)} >
                  <FaTimes />
              </button>
            </div>
```

Any insight as to why this is occurring is greatly appreciated. I have tried different formats to Bind *this* but i still end with the same result, which is an empty array being rendered.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your code works for me. How do you import and use `without` in your code?

Comment: import without from 'lodash'

Comment: wow im an idiot

Comment: Yeah it was {without} I needed I cant believe i overlooked that

Comment: Thanks alot, I wouldn't have even thought to look there I am so used to the NodeJS style

Comment: You are welcome. Small mistakes, nobody is an idiot :) I'm going to vote to close your question since the problem is all about a typo.